How to handle multiple URL requests in Java without timeout using multithreading?
I am trying to create an algorithm that makes multiple URL requests using several threads. The code works fine without multithreading, but when I add multiple threads, it runs for a few seconds and then starts throwing timeouts and SSL handshake errors. I believe this might be due to system overload.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solver {

    public static LinkedList<String> search(String start, String goal) {

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        List<String> neighborhood = Request.getLinks(start);

        var result = new AtomicReference<LinkedList<String>>();
        var atomicFound = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();

        for (var neighbor : neighborhood) {
            var thread = new Thread(() -> {
                LinkedList<String> path = BFS(neighbor, goal, visited, atomicFound);

                if (path != null) {
                    result.compareAndSet(null, path);
                    atomicFound.set(true);
                }
            });
            threads.add(thread);
            thread.start();
        }

        for (var thread : threads)
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return null;
            }

        return result.get();
    }

    public static LinkedList<String> BFS(String start, String goal, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> visited,
            AtomicBoolean atomicFound) {

        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> path = new HashMap<>();

        boolean found = false;

        queue.add(start);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

            if (atomicFound.get())
                return null;

            String current = queue.poll();

            if (visited.containsKey(current))
                continue;

            if (current.equals(goal) || found) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("=> " + current);
            List<String> neighborhood = Request.getLinks(current);

            for (String neighbor : neighborhood) {

                if (visited.containsKey(neighbor) || neighbor == null)
                    continue;

                path.putIfAbsent(neighbor, current);

                if (neighbor.equals(goal)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }

                queue.add(neighbor);
            }

            visited.put(current, true);
        }

        if (!found)
            return null;

        LinkedList<String> solution = new LinkedList<>();
        String it = goal;

        while (!it.equals(start)) {
            solution.addFirst(it);
            it = path.get(it);
        }
        solution.addFirst(start);

        return solution;
    }
}

The Request.getLinks function makes an HTTP request and parses the HTML. This is where I think the problem starts, as it works fine for a few seconds, but then I start getting errors like:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

I’ve tried increasing the timeout, but the host still terminates the connection. Here’s an example of the logs I get:
=> /wiki/Main_Page
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
Failed to retrieve HTML for /wiki/Madame_Tussauds
Failed to retrieve HTML for /wiki/Aaron_Carter

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this process more efficient without overloading the system or causing timeouts?
Here’s how I’m currently performing the requests:
public class Request {

    public static LinkedList<String> getLinks(String link) {
        LinkedList<String> links = new LinkedList<String>();
        String html = getHtml(link);

        if (html == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed to retrieve HTML for " + link);
            return links;
        }

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=\"(/wiki/[^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(html);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            links.add(URLDecoder.decode(matcher.group(1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }

        return links;
    }

    private static String getHtml(String link) {

        String urlString = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + link;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(inputLine);
                }
            }

            connection.disconnect();
            return builder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Is there a more efficient way to perform these requests while avoiding overloading the system?

Remote host terminated the handshake sounds like something a server would do if it didn’t appreciate your making so many simultaneous connections.
